# Get props value in method react/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am very new to react and redux. I have created an application using react/redux. I have implemented routing in the application and also have able to manage the state using redux. Now my problem is After set the state i am only able to get the props in render() not anywhere in the component. below are my code,

```
export class EmpSearch extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    Empnumber: ''
};
}

EmpSearch = (e) => {    
 if (e.key === 'Enter') {
 browserHistory.push('/Emp/' + e.target.value); 
 }
 }

updateEmpNumber(e) {

 this.props.dispatch({
        type: 'UPDATE_EMP_NUMBER',
        payload: e.target.value
    });
   }

 render() {
   return (
     <div className="row">
    <form>
    <div className="form-group">
    <label htmlFor="Empnumber">Emp Number</label>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="Empnumber" placeholder="Emp Number" value={this.props.Empnumber} onChange={this.updateEmpNumber.bind(this)} onKeyPress={this.EmpSearch}/>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
 );
 }
  }
 function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
Empnumber: state.Empnumber
 }
}

 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EmpSearch);
```

I want to pass the value to below component but instead of passing and getting value to render i want to create a method and want to pass the props there only.

```
class EmpDetail extends React.Component {
render() {
    const empNumber = this.props.Empnumber;
    return (
        <div className="container">
            Empnumber = {empNumber}
        </div>
    );
}
 }

 function mapStateToProps(state){
   return {
    Empnumber: state.Empnumber
 }
 }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EmpDetail);
```

I am successfully able to get the props value in render but could not in function.I have tried a lot to to create a method and pass the props to the method and get the props value but could not. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not binding your function and hence in the function `this` refers to the context of the function. Also `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount` will be executed only once and hence will contain only the inintial value

Second function

```
class EmpDetail extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.handleProp=this.handleProp.bind(this);


    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
         this.handleProp(nextProps);
    }
    handleProp(props) {
          console.log('In function' + props.Empnumber);
          return props.Empnumber;
    }
    render() {
        const empNumber = this.props.Empnumber;
        return (
            <div className="container">
                Empnumber = {this.props.Empnumber}
            </div>
        );
    }
     }

     function mapStateToProps(state){
       return {
        Empnumber: state.Empnumber
     }
     }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EmpDetail);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.not sure the way.. can you please write it for me.

Comment: I did not understand what you want, can you clarify more

Comment: I am able to get the 'empNumber' in the second code. but i can only get this in render(). instead of getting it in render only i want to create a new method in the second code above my example. and wanted to get the props value there. hope now you understand. if not i will edit my code. please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still not working. Throwing error, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"

Comment: you are still calling this method in render only. I want it to call on constructor or while loding the component. is it possible?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.. but i already tried this and also tried it now but it is not working.

Comment: I am not getting any error.. but vale of the props are undefined... i am getting in console.log --- In functionundefined

Comment: And it prints the correct result when you try to call the function from render()?

Comment: yes... at render it does print correct value.. that is why i was wondering that if we can only get the props in render not in any methods.

Comment: can you try one more thing, call the function in componentWillReceiveProps like in my updated answer. I suspect that when the component is called, the props are not available to to the component and later are. Do you see two console.logs in the render() component

Comment: I did.. but the problem is it get the older props.. i tried to get the current one but could not.. I am getting only one console.log

Comment: I think the updated answer where you pass the nextProps to the function will help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137655/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-user2768132).